# Filter docker containers by name and stop them

Tags: docker

I'm trying to stop all the containers starting with the name app_

I though this would work: `docker stop $(docker ps -f name="app_*")`, but it shows:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'docker stop --help'.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must put the complete filter expression into parantheses:

```
docker ps -f "name=app_*"
```

The search is fuzzy by default, so e.g. `name=app` will also return `my-app`.
You can use a regex to indicate that the match should be at the start:

```
docker ps -f "name=^app_"
```

You should further add the `quiet` flag `q` so that the command only returns ids to make it work with `docker stop`:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -qf "name=^app_")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command would work, if you had the `docker ps` show only the ID of containers.

I started some sleeping containers like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do 
   docker run --rm -d --name sleep_$i bash sleep 100000; 
done
```

And since they were all named `sleep_*` I could stop them like this:

```
docker ps -f Name=sleep_* --format '{{.ID}}' | xargs  docker stop
```

I usually use `xargs` rather than `$()` when possible for this kind of thing - for one reason, I can easily parallelize it with `-n 3 -P 10` (10 concurrent executions of 3 each):

```
$ docker ps -f Name=sleep_* --format '{{.ID}}' | xargs -n 3 -P 10  docker stop
c58a1fc538cf
98a9358734e4
e34828d3a7d7
ffbd2ec18775
1ba1e8a304e7
5e78aecb4ed6
cf86c4ea46aa
624a7d0342c2
7cb17ece1f0a
01665a084d02
```

Quite a lot faster for many containers.